# What happens when comments become a conversation?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I would like to know from those who have this modding privilege, when a comment thread becomes a conversation, do comments get deleted or do they get moved to a chat for the involved users to see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the situation. Generally, as long as comments are on-topic to their post, I will leave them. If comments are off-topic entirely, we will either migrate them to chat (if there are numerous comments between only a few users) or just delete them if they're old.